# REST for low latency messaging . 

Tags: sockets, rest, messaging, tibco

why dont you see more people using REST architecture for client server system.  You see people using sockets, or TIBCO RV or EMS or MQ but i haven't seen much basic REST architecture

does anyone know any reason why you would avoid using this architecture for client / server communication for high through put / low latency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that I would necessarily avoid it but I can think of a couple of reasons why I might not choose it for a high through-put, low latency service.  First, you have to deal with the entire web stack to get your message to your service.  This could introduce a number of unnecessary layers and services that would delay messages. A custom service need only support the protocol layers required by the service itself.

Second, unless your service is the only service hosted on the web server, you'll be competing with other requests for your messages to be serviced.  While having a custom endpoint for your service may not solve all resource contention problems, at least you don't have to compete for access from other services to your endpoint.

Third, a custom protocol need only support the actual service-related protocol information and may result in smaller packet sizes because you don't need to support the additional HTTP protocol overhead.  This would particularly effect protocols that exchange small messages as the header information would be a larger fraction of the message size.

Answer (score 8):

REST is not a good fit for every problem.

REST is best for *Resource* management. If you are writing web services (as with a client-server system) then you find you want things like language-agnostic data representation, argument validation, client/server code generation, error handling, access controls. REST basically requires you to code those things yourself.

On the other hand, it adds the HTTP layer. You get seamless integration of proxies, caching etc, but you do lose some speed due to HTTP headers, the webserver frontend, etc.